# How to set a SQL variable with either EXEC or sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to build a query on the fly that will set a variable. How would I do this?

Here is what I have so far

```
DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

set @SQL = 'set @maxRowCount = (select count(*) from Test)'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@maxRowCount int';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition
```

When I run this I get the following error

> Msg 8178, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The parameterized query '(@maxRowCount int)set @maxRowCount = (select count(*) from docto' expects the parameter '@maxRowCount', which was not supplied.

I am trying to get `@maxRowCount` to be set to the total row count of the `Test` table

Comment: do you actually need to use dynamic sql here or is this just a simplified example?

Comment: This is a very simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, you need the 'OUTPUT' in the parameter definition and a place where the result goes to as well

```
DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @iRowCount INT
SET @SQL = 'set @maxRowCount = (select count(*) from Test)'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@maxRowCount INT OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @maxRowCount = @iRowCount  OUTPUT

PRINT 'rowcount is:' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@iRowCount)
```